# How to update TFS workspace after computer name changes?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, workspace, tf-cli

I renamed my computer name, and now my TFS workspace is broken in Visual Studio 2012.

When I type:

```
tf workspaces /computer:ABOTONJIC-PC /owner:* /format:detailed
```

```
Workspace  : ABOTONJIC-PC
Owner      : wrongowner@test.com
Computer   : ABOTONJIC-PC
Comment    :
Collection : netuse.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection
Permissions: Private
Location   : Local
File Time  : Current
```

But I need to have :

```
Owner      : realowner@test.com
Computer   : NEW-PC
```

Then I try:

```
tf workspaces /updateComputerName:ABOTONJIC-PC /collection:netuse.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
```

```
No workspace matching *;wrongowner@test.com on computer NEW-PC found in Team Foundation Server netuse.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.
```

So my question are :

1. How to update computer name in my workspace?
2. Why TFS still shows "wrongowner@test.com" in workspace although there is new email registered as "realowner@test.com"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change computer name for a TFS Workspace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435135/change-computer-name-for-a-tfs-workspace)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. Install [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/). It's free.
2. Open the Workspace Sidekick, click Search, and select your workspace from the list.
3. Click the blue computer icon to *Update Workspace Computer Name* and you're done.

Comment: Is there any way to know which command the sidekicks application is executing?  I'm curious about the command it is using... I can't seem to figure out the command line option needed to do this.

Comment: This was huge.  Thanks.  I'm spreading the word around my group.  Computer name changes are a sticky one.

Comment: For Visual Studio 14, or using windows 8.1 +  , no function.

Comment: great tool. some very useful stuff .

Answer (score 49):

I installed Sidekicks. It did not work for this issue, but this did:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE>tf workspaces /updateComputerName:OldComputerName /s:"https://tfsServerName"
```

Comment: You need https vs. http in the server name above to make this work.  It wouldn't let me edit the post since an edit needs at least six characters which i really dumb when you are discussing programming and lines of code.

Comment: For the /s part i had to enter `http://servername:8080/tfs/projectcollectionname`  , substituting in my servername and projectcollectionname.

Answer (score 32):

I had the same issue, also a VisualStudio.com account.

I've tried what the prompt told me :

[image]

Like so :

`tf workspaces /updateComputerName:MyOldComputerName`

but I got back :

> The /collection option must be specified whenever /updateComputerName
>   or /updateUserName is specified.

In order to get the collection name I ran :

`tf workspaces`

which listed my collections and I got the name of my collection (...myusername.visualstudio.com...)

Then I ran :

`tf workspaces /collection:http://myusername.visualstudio.com /updateComputerName:MyOldComputerName`

Didn't work as I got this:

> TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server:
>   http://myusername.visuals tudio.com/defaultcollection. Team Foundation
>   Server Url: http://myusername.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection.
>
> Possible reasons for failure include:
>   - The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect
>   - The Team Foundation Server is offline.
>   - The password has expired or is incorrect.
>
> Technical information (for administrator): The remote server returned
>   an error: (404) Not Found.

Then I noticed that I've typed `http` instead of `https`, corrected, retried and it worked!

Comment: I'm convinced you just saved me 8 hours of hassle.  Thank you!

Comment: if fail login, add parameter >   /login:user,password

Comment: GODSEND. Thank you.

Comment: @Will: Glad to be of help! Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 16):

In

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>
```

run in CMD as admin this command

```
tf workspaces /collection:https://SERVER_NAME.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection /updateComputerName:OLD_COMPUTER_NAME
```

Answer (score 8):

To get this to work in Visual Studio 2017 use the following (new location)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe workspaces /collection:https://youraccountnamehere.visualstudio.com /updateComputerName:OLD-COMPUTERNAME
```

Hope this saves someone some time!

Answer (score 4):

Look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435135/change-computer-name-for-a-tfs-workspace)

Vaccano said :

This command did the trick:

```
tf workspaces /updateComputerName:MyOldComputerName 
/s:"http://MyServer:8080/tfs/MyCollection"
```

It had to be run from the computer I wanted to assign the workspace to (that is how it gets the new computer name.
>

Answer (score 3):

```
tf workspaces /updateComputerName:REPLCATEOLDCOMPUTERNAMEHERE /collection:REPLACETFSURL
```

example:

```
tf workspaces /updateComputerName:DESKTOP-42CLO97 /collection:https://testuserxx.visualstudio.com
```

VS2017

Answer (score 2):

Open Command prompt and type as shown in below

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE

[image]

and type the following code with your credential

> tf workspaces /updateComputerName:OldComputerName
>   /s:"https://tfsServerName"

In CMD prompt

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>tf
>   workspaces
>   /updateComputerName:OldComputerName/s:"https://tfsServerName"

Answer (score 1):

You can add new workspace then use vs 2017 delete your previous workspace: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the visual studio command prompt and type the following command

```
tf workspaces /updateComputerName:oldcomputername  /s:http://tfservername:port#/tfs
```

for example

```
tf workspaces /updateComputerName:abc-PC  /s:http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs
```

You can run the following command before and after running the above command, this is just to check the workspaces information on your computer.

**Remember:** *run all these commands on client computer (which is renamed) and not on the computer where TFS server is installed.*

If user name is also changed then run the following command

```
tf workspaces /updateUserName:oldUserName  /s:http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was typing

```
tf workspaces /updateComputerName:MyOldComputerName /collection:"anything".visualstudios.com/DefaultCollection/
```