# Allowing source control integration on a solution thats been moved to a new computer

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am moving to a new computer and want to shift my solutions I am currently working on over as well. Problem is, I have said solutions checked out and they are in the middle of being edited, so they won't build without errors. Opening the copied local files on the new computer, visual studio asks me if I want to connect to the server to try to enable source control integration. If I select yes, will it keep my current edits, but connect to source control for a future check in, or will source control overwrite what's currently checked out?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update TFS workspace after computer name changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216338/how-to-update-tfs-workspace-after-computer-name-changes)

Comment: If you copied the working folders to your new computer, you can update the workspace and keep the pending changes you have.  See the linked question above.

Comment: why don't you have a try, since you have made backup. I think all your current changes can be kept and you can check in later when you connect to source control.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a shelveset. Shelve your changes on the old computer, and then pull them down to your new computer That way you don't have to check them in and you don't lose your changes. Its a much safer way to go.

Comment: If @Rex_C has access to the old computer, this is an excellent suggestion.