# Machine name change - TFS Workspace and Get latest

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I understand the machine name change been asked multiple times but I could not find one which matches issue I am seeing.

I followed this stackoverflow article [Change computer name for a TFS Workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435135/change-computer-name-for-a-tfs-workspace) to change workspace name to reflect. So now all my mappings, look correct.

However, Source Control Explorer is showing all my mapped folders as "Not downloaded" even though I have all the folders replicated from my old system. I have tons of work which I did not "shelve" in and not checked in as well.

However, I do not have TFS Admin rights, so is that the reason my changes are not reflecting in my new system? Microsoft article says you need Admin rights or use "/login" etc.

What is the way to go now, since I do not want to lose all my work? I can do a "Get Latest" and then copy over it, but is there a better way?

Edit: I already have the new computer name/mapping reflected correctly. Question is only about source code showing up as "Not downloaded".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a get latest at which point, it show all modified files and allowed me to take latest or keep local ones. (I did a backup to be on the safe side before doing a "Get latest")

Answer (score 1):

Can you open the workspaces option under File-> Source Control and in the "manage workspace", delete the added workspace (named as your current computer name), and rename the old one to your current computer name?

That should take care of the not downloaded/pending changes issue.

Please use this [LInk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245466(v=vs.90).aspx) to edit/modify the workspace details.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wan't clear. The article I followed had me do the computer name change. So I was already with the new name and mapping was also showing up. However, all source code was still showing as "Not downloaded" even though the mapping was shown. I had to do a get latest at which point, it show all modified files and allowed me to take latest or keep local ones. (I did a backup to be on the safe side before doing a "Get latest").