# Renaming computer broke TFS binding

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

Had to rename my PC and it has caused hiccups to TFS. All solutions in my workspace seem to be disassociated from source control.

File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control

[image]

Running this command referred in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435135/change-computer-name-for-a-tfs-workspace) did not make any obvious difference:

`tf workspaces /updateComputerName:oldPCName /s:"https://tfs-host-url/tfs/OurSolutions"`

I'm thinking maybe deleting the old workspace entry from VS Manage Workspaces dialog might make a difference in running the above command? When I try to remove the old workspace (after clicking Show Remote Workspaces), I get this message:

> Are you sure you want to delete the selected workspaces? All pending
>   changes in the selected workspaces will be lost. This operation is permanent.

Question: What exactly does this message mean? I won't lose the pending changes that are sitting on my disk (old workspace) correct? And I can check them in once new workspace is created? So what exactly will be lost?

Visual Studio 2017: Version 15.7.6

TFS: Version 16.131.27701.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Deleting a Workspace**
>
> If you delete a workspace that contains pending changes, Team
>   Foundation **cancels the pending changes as part of the delete
>   process**. Deleting a workspace does not delete the files and folders
>   on the client computer that were in that workspace.

*Workspace Modified. One or more working folders in version control have changed. Do you want to get the latest files from version control to update your workspace*

This is an expected behavior, since your work folders changed, there are no mappings between the server and local. A better way is getting files and establishing mappings from  server side first.

Then copy your back-up files/folders from old workspace folder to the new one. Windows system will judge to replace files and add new files. After this, TFS system will auto detect the changes in local and will list them as new pending changes. Some new add files maybe stay in the Excluded list, manually promote them in Included list.

Finally check in pending changes, everything should get back to normal.

Comment: Expected behavior after renaming a computer? I beg to differ :)

Comment: In my case Windows started copying some 100K/10GB files and did not prompt for overwriting the existing files with the same name until about half way through...or about 15 minutes later. Adding here just in case you get anxious like I got :)

Comment: @joym8 Thanks for your kindly sharing. Also sorry for caused the misunderstanding. I didn't explain clearly, it should be the expected behavior for the prompt dialog which after workspace changed.  It should work when you use the `workspaces command  /updateComputerName` in most cases.  That's just designed in case you have to do a newly get & map after computer name changed. There maybe something wrong in your local machine. However, you already deleted and created the new workspace when you posted this ticket. Thus, we do not need to take time digging into it. Appreciate your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Your pending changes will still be there in the old workspace.  Once you create the new workspace in a different location copy your old files over into it, and you will be able to check in those pending changes.  Iw will likely want to check in everyfile, but that is ok.

Comment: The TFS message means basically nothing then?

Comment: Well, the pending changes are lost in a sense.  They no longer will show up in the pending changes view because it will no longer be looking at that workspace.  But those changes will still be on your local, you will just need to copy them over to the new workspace.

Comment: After creating new folder, and then pointing new workspace to that folder, VS says "Workspace Modified. One or more working folders in version control have changed. Do you want to get the latest files from version control to update your workspace?" So you want me to cancel this message, copy the projects from old workspace folder to new one?

Comment: You can get latest, then just copy your old files over it and check in.